# How do I get the Eon Ticket?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have Latios and its mega stone. I have a Latiasite too, and I wish to get Latias with the Eon Ticket. Therefore, I turned on Streetpass and so far I found no ticket. From what I've learned you need to pass someone who has the ticket. If anyone knows who they are please tell me.

Answer (score 4):

"From what I've learned you need to pass someone who has the ticket"

This is pretty much it. The Eon Ticket started off with around 10 people receiving a physical copy of it, which can be downloaded into the game. Through StreetPass, if you pass someone holding an Eon Ticket, you will receive it. It's like a plague.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eon_Ticket) The only way to get an Eon ticket is by attending an event

EDIT: There are some ways if you live in London & New York City

Comment: That was for Generation 3. This is for Generation 6

Comment: True, but if you read the Generation 6 section. It says the tickets are given to thousands in the USA and to 15 in the UK. which is extremely, extremely low. The chances of coming across anybody, if you live in the mainland of Europe, who has his 3ds in sleep mode and has an ticket is extremely slim

Comment: Not really. Here in Australia it's common. I myself have one

Comment: Your luck then, i keep my 3ds on sleep mode every day while i travel from and to work but i only encounter 1 person every few weeks. Which only plays petdogs etc.

Comment: That's very interesting. I encounter the exact opposite, although I do go through the City

Comment: Me to, My work & study is one of the Major city networks here(Rotterdam, Netherlands). i travel like 80km a day without any luck. I think a cultural difference is whats the problem is. Here the handheld devices are used for kids mostly. to the age of say 12-13.

Answer (score 0):

A good workaround is to set your own [Homepass relay](http://www.reddit.com/r/3DS/comments/1k0g58/setting_up_a_streetpass_relay_at_home) to get a lot of StreetPasses from all over the world without going out. [Here](https://gbatemp.net/threads/how-to-have-a-homemade-streetpass-relay.352645/)'s a guide about it.

I don't know if it still works, because something changed with the latest update. People say that Nintendo resets the StreetPass relay servers with each update. 
Another reason could be that the very major point release of the firmware makes systems on the new version unable to streetpass systems on the old version, and it takes a while after the update initially goes out for everyone to get on the new version.

Give it a few days and it will work again, I hope.